# Fatal error: Cannot redeclare class Zend_XmlRpc_Value (Wordpress Plugin)

Tags: php, wordpress, class, zend-framework, plugins

I'm in the process of a plugin development.

And that plugin uses `Zend_XmlRpc_Client`. I have developed a similar plugin which uses the same classes.

When I use the two plugins together, I got error.

So I was trying to use something like this:

```
if (!in_array('Zend_XmlRpc_Client', get_declared_classes()) && 
    !in_array('Zend_XmlRpc_Value', get_declared_classes()) && 
    !in_array('Zend_XmlRpc_Value_Scalar', get_declared_classes()) && 
    !in_array('Zend_XmlRpc_Value_String', get_declared_classes())) {

    require_once(DIR_PATH . 'library/Zend/XmlRpc/Client.php');
}
```

I am getting in the if statement because aparently the class `Zend_XmlRpc_Value` is not declared.
If I try to print_r all the declared classes before this require_once I cannot find `Zend_XmlRpc_Value` but if I do it after, I get that error, and find the class declared.

Thanks

Comment: Seems a very inefficient way of doing it when [`class_exists`](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.class-exists.php) uh, exists.

Comment: Also do you have a similar check in the other plugin?

Comment: Max, i had class_exists before, but to make sure, used that method.

Comment: And yes, it is also in the other plugin.. :/

Comment: Why wrap the require_once in an `if` to begin with? If its already been loaded, it won't be loaded again. Is your other plugin also using `require_once` ?

Comment: Oscar M. I do know that, but since it started to have that error, I am trying to do everything.
And yes, the other plugin also has that. Although, each plugin has it's own library folder... could that have to do with it?

Comment: @OscarM. require_once will not work if there are two different files with the same class declaration.

Comment: That is what I have. Shouldn't the in_array or the class_exists aproach work?

Comment: You can just use only `if(!class_exists('Zend_XmlRpc_Client', false))`. That should work

Comment: tried that.. still not working ... :/

Comment: Just noticed that the error, is related to the files in the other plugin!

Could it be possible that class_exists cant figure that out?

Comment: @Max create another plugin to supply one copy of Zend_XmlRpc_Client and make your plugins require that one. Better in the long than having two potentially different copies of the class, that's just inviting weird bugs to happen.

Comment: @OscarM. That would be weird, making the clients install two plugins to just use one. Am I missing anything about class_exists() function when we have the same files in different directories? I've been reading about in php documentation.

Comment: Boom: https://wordpress.org/plugins/zend-framework-wp/ Done

Comment: @OscarM. Would you consider that a good practice?

Comment: Certainly (and FWIW Drupal does this a lot, have modules that other modules depend on). You should only have one copy of a class in your codebase (DRY)